# How to write text of a same file to multiple text files in c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file of 11 bytes now i want to split and write the text to multiple files say 2 bytes for each file and 3 for the last file how to do this using c#

For now here is my code which writes the whole file to a new file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             this.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileName = Text;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            var size = fi.Length;
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(size);
            int j = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            decimal ireminder = (decimal)i % j;

            MessageBox.Show(ireminder.ToString());
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\Test.txt");
            sw.WriteLine(line);
            sw.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: tell us why did you need that?

Comment: I have a button labeled split so when i click the button the write operation should take place

Comment: Why do you convert *fi.Length* (a `long`) into an `int` just to cast it to a `decimal` right there after? My head is spinning... Just do `long ireminder = fi.Length % Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);`.

Comment: You open only one file "D:\Test.txt" for writing. To write to multiple files, you should obviously open and write to multiple files (hint: use loops)